# .htaccess : redirect permanent and stop new rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have that rule that works well

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*?)-/(.*)$ /$1/$2
```

It redirects for instance

> http://example.com/category-/list/town/id/id2/country ->
>
> http://example.com/category/list/town/id/id2/country

Problem is, later .htaccess adds some extra query parameters.

My goal is: when this rule is matches, then do not apply other .htaccess rules

I tried with:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*?)-/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

and rule is not applied at all !

Comment: It would be `RewriteRule ^(.*?)-/(.*)$ ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @hjpotter92 mentioned in the comments, the pattern is *without* the leading slash in .htaccess files. See [`Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/tech.html#InternalAPI)

> In per-directory context (i.e., within .htaccess files and Directory blocks), these rules are being applied after a URL has already been translated to a filename. Because of this, the URL-path that mod_rewrite initially compares RewriteRule directives against is the full filesystem path to the translated filename with the current directories path (including a trailing slash) removed from the front.
>
> To illustrate: If rules are in /var/www/foo/.htaccess and a request for `/foo/bar/baz` is being processed, an expression like `^bar/baz$` would match.

[`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) has a similar note in the section "Per-directory Rewrites".

So your rule should look like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)-/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R,L]
```

---

If you have this `RewriteRule`, you don't need the `RedirectMatch` anymore.